# Removing the constant term from the derivative？

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Suppose there is a binary function $f(x, y)$, which can be seen as a binary function. Its derivative sum can also be calculated as shown below:

$$
\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}*y + \frac{df(x,y)}{dy}*\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}*y
$$

If $y$ is a constant, then $f(x, y)$ will degenerate into a unary function. In that case, the derivative of y should be 0. What can I do to achieve this function?

$$
\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}*y + \frac{df(x,y)}{dy}*\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}*y=\frac{df(x,y_0)}{dx}*y_0,y_0 \,is \, a \, constant
$$

Comment: Define a new function f1[x]= f[x,yconst]

Comment: Definition may be a feasible method, but are there any more elegant ways?One more thing is that my function is an abstract function without a specific expression.@DanielHuber

Comment: I think you are asking for the total derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative (in which case you are lacking a dx and dy in the formula you wrote). Mathematica has `Dt`. In the documentation for `Dt`, you may see in the details sections a syntax that looks like this example: `Dt[x*y, Constants -> {y}]`

Comment: Dt can indeed achieve this. I just gave an example here. In practice, it may contain second-order derivatives or something, and it is not in the form of summation. What should I do? @userrandrand

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking, `D[f[x, y], x]` for example takes the partial derivative of `f` with respect to `x`.

Comment: For example `D[x^n*y, x]`

Comment: My point is that my expression is an abstract one with various derivatives in it. Sometimes, when y is a constant, I should eliminate the terms related to the derivative with respect to y@userrandrand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What I understood:**

You already have an expression that contains derivatives of x and y for example:

```
D[f[x, y], y]*D[f[x, y], y] + D[f[x, y], {x, 2}]^3 + 
 D[f[x, y], {y, 4}]^3 + D[f[x, y], x, y]
```

$$f^{(0,4)}(x,y)^3+f^{(2,0)}(x,y
   )^3+f^{(0,1)}(x,y)^2+f^{(1,
   1)}(x,y)$$

and you want to obtain this expression when all derivatives in the direction of y are zero.

---

If I understood the question correctly here are some possible solutions:

```
D[f[x, y], y]*D[f[x, y], y] + D[f[x, y], {x, 2}]^3 + 
  D[f[x, y], {y, 4}]^3 + D[f[x, y], x, y] /. 
 Derivative[_, m_][f][x, y] /; m > 0 :> 0
```

$$f^{(2,0)}(x,y)^3$$

```
D[f[x, y], y]*D[f[x, y], y] + D[f[x, y], {x, 2}]^3 + 
  D[f[x, y], {y, 4}]^3 + D[f[x, y], x, y] /. f :> (f[y][#1] &)
```

$$\left(f(y)''(x)\right)^3$$